# MySQL datatype concern

Tags: mysql

I have to store output with special characters like $, >,[,], @ etc.
I'm not sure which datatype should I use while creating the table in MySQL.
Could anybody please help me? Also, should I change collation into utf_general_ci or utf_unicode_ci? I'm not sure if I need to change the collation.

Comment: Do you know what collation is and what character set is?

Comment: Collation is the rule used to compare strings. That's the algorithm which says letter B comes after A and so on, to put it simply. It's used when you want to order something in your query based on column containing strings. Unicode is a list of "letters", to simplify and UTF-8 is a variable-encoding that makes using Unicode more space efficient. So, to put it in simple terms - UTF-8 are letters, Collation is the alphabet-rule. You want a column that stores textual data. That's char, varchar and text. If you don't like too much reading, use `text` type.

Answer (score 0):

Your collation should be fine. Depending on how large it will be, you can use `varchar` or `text`.

Comment: Say, I had to store something like $Assurance >= 200 and $Community rel "" and $Type in [ "UUU", "YUHP", "WOC" ]....what would I use?

Answer (score 0):

you can use varchar for storing these as string